Is Dampati (from Rig Veda 8.31. 6) a deity?
This verse from 8th Mandala of Rig Veda shows that the devata (deity) of this verse is Dampati:-

प्रति॑ प्राश॒व्याँ॑ इतः स॒म्यञ्चा॑ ब॒र्हिरा॑शाते । न ता वाजे॑षु वायतः ॥
प्रति प्राशव्याँ इतः सम्यञ्चा बर्हिराशाते । न ता वाजेषु वायतः ॥
prati prāśavyām̐ itaḥ samyañcā barhir āśāte | na tā vājeṣu vāyataḥ ||
English translation:
“Constantly associated, may they acquire appropriate (sacrificial) viands; may they be able to offersacrifice; may the never be wanting in food (given by the gods).”

Ṛṣi (sage/seer): manurvaivasvataḥ [manurvaivasvata];
Devatā (deity/subject-matter): dampatī ;
Chandas (meter): nicṛdgāyatrī ;
Svara (tone/note): Swar;

I know that Dampati is usually means a couple. But, Is there any deity named "Dampati"? If so, are any other details available for Dampati? But, If not, who is the exact devata for this verse?
